# When I call my reverse queue function, it keeps showing me only one data

Tags: java, data-structures

I need to reverse my queue, but when I call my reverse function, it keeps showing only one data.
I think there should be something wrong with my dequeue function, but I couldn't find where is the problem.

my dequeue funtion:

```
public String dequeue(){ //get and remove the front node from the queue
        // check if it's empty
        if(this.rear == null){
            System.out.println("Queue is empty");
            return "Null";
        }else if(this.rear.getNext() == null){
            Node tmp = this.front;
            this.front = null;
            this.rear = null;
            return tmp.getData();
        }
        else{
            String data = front.getData();
            front = front.getNext();
            return data;
        }
    }
```

My enqueue function:

```
public void enqueue(Node node){ //insert one node at the end of the queue
        if(this.front == null){  
            this.rear = node;
            this.front = this.rear;
            return;
        }
        this.rear.setNext(node);
        this.rear = node;
    }
```

My push function and my pop function:

```
public void push(Node node){ //push a node into stack
        node.setNext(this.top);
        this.top = node;
    }

public Node pop(){ //get and remove the top node from this stack
        //check if it is empty
        if(this.top == null){
            System.out.println("Stack is empty");
            return null;
        }else{
            Node currentTop = this.top;
            this.top = this.top.getNext();
            currentTop.setNext(null);
            return currentTop;
        }
    }
```

My reverse function:

```
public static MyQueue reverseQueue(MyQueue queue){
        if(!queue.isEmpty()){
            MyStack s = new MyStack();
            String x;
            while(!queue.isEmpty()){
                x = queue.dequeue();
                s.push(new Node(x));
            }
            while(!s.isEmpty()){
                queue.enqueue(s.pop());
            }
            return queue;
        }else{
            System.out.println("empty queue");
            return queue;
        }
    }
```

My test:

```
MyQueue queue = new MyQueue();
        queue.enqueue(new Node("1"));
        queue.displayQueue();
        queue.enqueue(new Node("2"));
        queue.displayQueue();
        queue.enqueue(new Node("3"));
        queue.displayQueue();
        // queue.dequeue();
        // queue.displayQueue();
        System.out.println(queue.isEmpty());

        reverseQueue(queue);
        queue.displayQueue();
```

in the terminal, it shows:

```
1
12
123
false
1
```

Answer (score 1):

As for me, in your method dequeue() something's wrong in else-if-block:

```
this.front = null;
this.rear = null;
```

Are you sure you're not erasing the links to next nodes?
Look, you have statement:

```
else if(this.rear.getNext()==null)
```

Does **this.rear.getNext()** not **always equal null**?
Apparently, this condition is met in first iteration, integer 1 is going onto the stack, but the other links are erased by those to lines.

Comment: if i remove .getNext(), it will show me : can not invoke node.getData(), because this.front is null.

Comment: try to replace in else-if condition : `else if (this.front.getNext()==0)`

Comment: I meant else if `(this.front.getNext()==null)` .